# Test for primality by using numbers 2 to 9

Tags: prime-numbers

What is a number that is not prime and is not divisible by numbers 2 to 9? If a number is not divisible by numbers 2 to 9 can i say it's a prime number?

Comment: No.  $143=11\cdot13$ is not prime and not divisible by any of these numbers.

Comment: Same with $121=11\cdot11$

Comment: $11\times 13$ isn't prime and is not divisible by any number from $2$ to $9$. What do  single digit numbers have so special?

Comment: I didn't think about multiplication between prime numbers, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalizing your problem, imagine there is no composite number that's not divisible by the numbers 2 to n. This interval includes the primes $2,3,5,\dots,p$ (p is the last prime less than n) which means that any composite number can be divided by at least one of these primes. Now consider the number $(2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots p) +1$. It's clearly not divisible by any of the primes in the product. If it is a composite number, we proved our assumption wrong, and if it is a prime, it is necessarily a prime we didn't have before, just square it and we have a new composite number.

If primes are infinite then no interval can divide all composite numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Every integer $n>1$ is either a prime number or can be written as a product of primes. There's nothing too special about the first few primes in particular.